# Can't use environment variable in Flask

Tags: python, flask

To get `CLIENT_ID` set up `instances/application.cfg`, I'm using `current_app` but it's not working.

The error:

> KeyError: 'CLIENT_ID'

```py
from flask import current_app

# Authentication
@app.route('/auth/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def authorize():
    client_id = current_app.config['CLIENT_ID']
```

**app/instance/application.cfg**

```py
CLIENT_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
CLIENT_SECRET='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

**app/config.py**

```py
import os

class BaseConfig(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False  

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'

class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

config = {
    "default": "main.config.BaseConfig",
    "development": "main.config.DevelopmentConfig",
    "production": "main.config.ProductionConfig",
}

def configure_app(app):
    config_name= os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('application.cfg', silent=True)
```

**app/__init__.py**

```py
# Initialized app
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
configure_app(app)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask
from config import DevelopmentConfig

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)

@app.route('/auth/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def authorize():
    client_id = current_app.config['CLIENT_ID']
```

**app/config.py**

```
class BaseConfig:
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    CLIENT_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    CLIENT_SECRET='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///app.db'

class ProductionConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

hope this help you